# Can zip files be cracked if they were split into parts and only one part was available?

Tags: encryption, privacy, file-encryption, password-cracking, zip

I am talking here about zip files that were compressed using basic protection and those using AES protection. In both cases, if only one of the many parts of the zip were available, will it be able to crack it?

Comment: define "available" - do you mean you only have one part still zipped, or do you mean you have successfully unzipped and decrypted one part of the full zip?

Answer (score 4):

What you describe here is called a known-plaintext attack. The attacker has at least part of the plaintext, and tries to use it to figure out the key.

AES and all other modern encryption algorithms must be able to withstand this type of attack. So the answer is no.

Comment: what about "zipcrypto" encryption?